# How to include css/js in html for node http server

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, http

I'm new here.

I have a website (`index.html`) where several *css* and *js* files are included. Locally it works fine, but if I start the node-http server (which calls the `index.html`), the website (`localhost:8080`) doesn't know the files. It shows me only basic text (i.e. `<h1>`) which have nothing to do with the javascript files. I checked the source code in the browser to see the `index.html`. But if I click on the *css* and *js* links, I'll be forwarded back to index.html.

I assume, it's a linking problem. Or do you think the problem could be in the node http server implementation? It would be very helpful for me if you could give me some support.

Thanks and best wishes,
Kevin

**webServer.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var connect = require('connect');
var http = require('http');

var path = "";

var app = connect().use(express.static(__dirname + path));
http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
```

**index.html:**

head:

```
<!-- Cascading Style Sheets  -->
<link href="css/custom.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="css/rickshaw.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="css/envision.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

body:

```
<h1>Data monitoring</h1>

<!-- Drawing rickshaw based charts -->
<div id="chart-type1"></div>
<div id="chart-type2"></div>
<!-- Drawing envision based charts -->
<div id="chart-TimeSeries"></div>
<div id="chart-RealTime"></div>

<!-- JavaScript  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/rickshaw.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/chart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/chartTimeSeries.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/chartRealTime.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/collectionJson.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's much more likely that you forgot to add a static route for the static files, but as you've posted no code, it's hard to say.

Comment: I have the same problem. May I ask how you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define routes for all your files in a way like this:

```
var http = require ('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var port = '8080';

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   if (request.url === '/') {
       fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data){
          res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
          res.end(data, 'utf-8');
       });
   } else if (request.url === '/css/custom.css') {
       /*Read /css/custom.css file*/
   } else if (request.url === '/path/to/other.file') {
       /*Read /path/to/other.file*/
   }
}).listen(port);
```

But this is difficult to read and write so it's better to use a Web Framework for this. You can try Express or the framework written by me: [Simples](https://github.com/micnic/simpleS/). You can put all your static files in a directory then use this code:

```
var simples = require('simples');

var server = new simples(8080);

server.serve('path/to/staticFiles');

// or in some special cases:

server.get('/some_url', function (connection) {
    connection.header('X-Some-Header', 'Header Value'); // Set a header
    connection.drain('some_local_file.ext');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using framework such as express,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

You host all static files in the Public folder as follows:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

If you have a folder by a specific name as ‘media’:

```
app.use('/media', express.static(__dirname + '/media'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't used the express framework yet, but I have it already installed. How I have to implement your lines into my webServer.js (see edit above)? Especially, when the css files are in a "css" folder and the js files in a "js" folder? Thank you!

Comment: Just use the above and add all your HTML CSS js folders in the public folder and add this line app.listen(5000); or whatever port you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either express or connect (install them with npm) to create an app that you will host with `http.createServer()`. You will write in `webServer.js`:

```
var http = require('http');
var connect = require('connect');
var app = connect().use(connect.static(__dirname + path));
http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
```

where `path` is the path from your root folder (where you have `webServer.js`) to your `index.html` folder (`path` is an empty string if `index.html` and `webServer.js` are in the same folder).

Then, in the html page where you have a link to any css or js, you just have to put the path from the folder where the html page is to your css or js file. For example, I have `webServer.js` in `root`, html in `html` folder and js in `js` folder. In my html I will put: `<script src="../js/myjsfile.js"></script>`.

Be careful, you will not be able to find paths that go higher than the server root directory.

Comment: That's exactly what I did in the html page. But I just tried your code for the webServer.js...TypeError: Object function createServer(){...} has no mehod 'static'.

Comment: You should give us your whole and exact code from `webServer.js` if we want to understand why you get this error... I could not reproduce it.

Comment: It is precisely the version _after_ you include my code that I wish to see. You do not have to add my code to your previous one. Actually my only code in webServer.js should be enough. All the rest (js and css) should be in your html.

Comment: I edited the webServer.js in the orignal Question on the top. Now, I have no errors and I can start the webServer.js.In the brower, the links are working! Yeah, thank you! But with the css and js I want to show some charts. The charts are still not visualized in the browser.

Comment: Now I think this is a different question. You should close this one and ask an other one I think ;).

Comment: Yes your right. I just realized, that it doesn't work locally anymore. So it's definitely another issue. Thank you very much for your help! And sorry for my "newcomer-mess" here on this question/site.

Answer (score -1):

Use this in your html file

```
<script>
     $.getScript("/js/yourjsfile.js", function () {
       //alert("Script loaded and executed.");
       // Here you can use anything you defined in the loaded script
    });
</script>
```